# How can I separate address content without comma and delimiter? (Street/City/State/Zipcode)

Tags: excel-formula

I want to separate Address Field into their own columns such as: Street Address -City - State - Zipcode

I would like to do this with formula not with a macro.

Example:

```
1 NE 2nd St Oklahoma City OK 73104
1 Scotdale Rd La Grange Park IL 60526
1 Warner Ct Huntington NY 11743
10 Foothills Blvd Ste 160 Roseville CA 95747
```

I was able to figure out how to get the State Abbreviation and Zipcode extracted but not the City.

There are no comma's or delimiters making this more challenging.

I got the zipcode with the following formula.

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("-",RIGHT(TRIM(A2),5),1)),RIGHT(TRIM(A2),5),RIGHT(TRIM(A2),10))
```

I got the State abbreviation with the following formula.

```
=MID(A1,LOOKUP(10^99,INDEX(FIND(" "&$I$3:$I$52&" ",A1)+1,0)),2)
```

I even tried some Macros but no success. I want to separate Address Field into their own columns such as: Street Address -City - State - Zipcode

Comment: Unless you can find a pattern that you can exploit there is no method that will work.

Comment: The only way I can think of is if you had a list of all the cities possible, then you can search for those in each address and return the one that matches.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can since it's possible that both the street and the city could potentially be the same name. By the way, it should easily be able to identify the zip and state, simply by looking at the string in reverse, where by your data, the last 8 characters always appear to be STATE SPACE ZIP.  Of course it's bad practice to design routines based on data.

Comment: This problem is so difficult, that there are vendors doing this as a service.  Including USPS.  It is much easier to find a service.   ZIP code via USPS might give you a list of City names, which could be matched to incoming address, and the left-hand remainder would be Street address.

Comment: I used to do this by sorting how much words there were in the line, then separating them using Text to Columns. Then I tackled every group depending on the numbers of words independently. It's not fast way. You can also extract ZIP and based on that search state and city using databases in Internet. Than what you have left is your address. Also not a very fast way